# Checking for panic without recovering from it

Tags: error-handling, go

In a defer function, I want to see whether a call to recover would yield a non-nil value (without recovering)

Is it possible?

Comment: Just re-panic with whatever non-nil return `recover` gave.

Comment: Dave's answer is the best what works. The answer to your question is a plain "No.".

Comment: Why do you think you need to do this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That exact thing isn't possible. You probably just want to re-panic, basically like re-throwing an exception in other languages;

```
        defer func() {
             if e := recover(); e != nil {
                 //log and so other stuff
                 panic(e)
             }
          }()
```

Comment: wouldn't the stack trace overridden by the new panic? **EDIT**: nevermind, it isn't https://play.golang.org/p/4E5hJZY_qA-

Comment: It is not overridden, but it does gets extended, what can make stacktrace looks strange.

Answer (score 5):

You can set a bool flag and then reset it at the end of the body of your function. If the flag is still set inside defer, you know that the last statement did not execute. The only possible reason for that is that the function is panicking.

https://play.golang.org/p/PKeP9s-3tF

```
func do() {
    panicking := true
    defer func() {
        if panicking {
            fmt.Println("recover would return !nil here")
        }
    }()

    doStuff()

    panicking = false
}
```

The disadvantage is that there is added maintenance burden, as `panicking = false` must be kept as the last statement in the function body. If the function has multiple returns, it must be the last statement before every return.

Comment: This answer is incorrect due to [runtime.Goexit](https://pkg.go.dev/runtime#Goexit), which behaves exactly like panicking (stopping execution), but recover() will return nil. https://go.dev/play/p/qytk3Gdv15k

Answer (score 0):

The solution does not have "direct" paths

```
package main

import(
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
    "regexp"
)


var re_runtimepanicdetector *regexp.Regexp = regexp.MustCompile("runtime/panic.go$");

func tester_for_panic( deferdepth int )bool{
    _,file,_,_ := runtime.Caller(deferdepth+3)
    return re_runtimepanicdetector.MatchString(file)
}

func tester_for_panic_worktest() bool {
    defer func(){ 
        recover() ;
        if !tester_for_panic(0) { panic("tester_for_panic: NOT WORK!!") } 
    }();
    panic(1)
}
var Iswork_tester_for_panic bool= tester_for_panic_worktest();


func testp( dopanic bool ) {  
        defer func() { 
            fmt.Println("defer panic=", tester_for_panic(0)) ; 
            recover() // optional   
        }()
     if (dopanic) { panic("test")  }
    }


func main(){
    testp(true) 
    testp(false)
}
```

Comment: Can you expand your answer to explain how this answers the question? What is this code doing, and how is it relevant?

Comment: code is an example of detecting panic without recovering