# Can I recover from panic, handle the error, then panic again and keep the original stack trace?

Tags: go, error-handling, stack-trace, panic

Is it possible to "rethrow" an error from `recover` and keep the original stack trace? The best I know how to do is to panic again, but that does create a new stacktrace.

```
func do() {
    defer func() {
        cleanUp()
        if x := recover(); x != nil {
            handleError()
            panic(x)
        }
    }()
    doStuff()
}
```

My motivation for wanting this is that unless my function exits normally or `handleError` runs, my program deadlocks. And unless I preserve the original strack trace, I do not know where it crashed.

Comment: Related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30062949/golang-checking-for-panic-without-recovering-from-it

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The solution is to not call `recover`, because then neither rethrowing nor accessing the stack trace is possible. Use a bool flag instead of `recover` to check for panic.

https://play.golang.org/p/PKeP9s-3tF

```
func do() {
    panicked := true
    defer func() {
        cleanUp()
        if panicked {
            handleError()
        }
    }()
    doStuff()
    panicked = false
}
```

Comment: Note that this approach means you shouldn't return anywhere in `do()` except at the end, below `panicked = false`. Or you'll have to explicitly set `panicked = false` before any other return statement, which is error-prone. Anyone modifying this function later needs to understand this or will regress the logic in the deferred func. I do wish `panic`s could be "re-thrown" as in Java or C# to preserve the original stack trace without resorting to this.

Comment: This proposed Go feature will help accomplish it better: [proposal: Go 2 error values #29934](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/29934)

Comment: Is this answer still correct? Looking at the [std library](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/fmt/scan.go#L253) they "rethrow" the panic after recovering.
The problem I have with not recovering is that I can't get access to the underlying error and stack trace without doing so.

Answer (score 6):

Defered functions higher up in the stack will run on panic, even if they don't call `recover()`.

Simply remove the if-statement and the re-panic. Then handle your error, and let the panic continue up the stack.

```
func do() {
    defer handleError()
    doStuff()
}
```

a simple demo:

https://play.golang.org/p/UiRou5MhUR

```
func a() {
    defer func() {
        fmt.Println("a")
    }()
    panic("test")
}
func b() {
    defer func() {
        fmt.Println("b")
    }()
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
    b()
}
```

outputs

```
Hello, playground
b
```

Comment: That would work in some cases, but not for me. I call handleError only if there actually is an error. What handleError does is to cause some other gorutines to terminate so that they do not deadlock. I do not want to kill them when there was no error. When there is no error, I do something different. I added a `cleanUp()` call to the question to show what I mean.

Comment: Then you can set a boolean variable, named "succ", initially set to false, and set to true at the end of the function. If succ is set, do not call handleError.

Answer (score 1):

As [Daniel Conde Marin questioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34842322/can-i-recover-from-panic-handle-the-error-then-panic-again-and-keep-the-origin#comment123691814_34851179)

I do not believe you need to worry about calling panic and passing in a recover()'s response object creating a cryptic or "new" stack trace, at least in go 1.17. It looks like doing so simply adds another "src/runtime/panic.go:<linenum>" frame to the trace.

See this example test:
https://goplay.space/#5i1RCJyiFJr

Go does not treat panics like other languages treat try/catch/throw/finally.

Comment: That’s amazing :).